# Need help on my time series chart. its showing the same value if you tap on a specific line in the chart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, dart-html

So I am stuck into trying to paint the different value for a selected line in a time series chart. soo basically what I am trying to achieve is show the comparison on the values inside the series of the chart. I will upload some code and embed the deployed link for the sample program. this was done using dart and flutter

This is the code that is responsible for the series inside the chart:

```
List<charts.Series<StockSeries, DateTime>> series = [
  charts.Series(
      id: "strategyReturns",
      data: chartData,
      domainFn: (StockSeries series, _) => series.date,
      measureFn: (StockSeries series, _) => series.strategyReturns,
      colorFn: (StockSeries series, _) => series.strategyReturnsColor),
  charts.Series(
      id: "pSEiReturns",
      data: chartData,
      domainFn: (StockSeries series, _) => series.date,
      measureFn: (StockSeries series, _) => series.pSEiReturns,
      colorFn: (StockSeries series, _) => series.pSEiReturnsColor),
];
```

this is the code that is responsible for drawing the chart and here also is where I think the problem is:

```
return Container(
  height: 500,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
  child: Card(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "Chart",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: charts.TimeSeriesChart(
          series,
          animate: true,
          defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(),
          dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
          behaviors: [
            charts.SeriesLegend(),
            charts.SlidingViewport(),
            charts.PanAndZoomBehavior(),
            charts.LinePointHighlighter(
              symbolRenderer: CustomCircleSymbolRenderer(),
            )
          ],
          selectionModels: [
            charts.SelectionModelConfig(
                changedListener: (charts.SelectionModel model) {
              if (model.hasDatumSelection) {
                final value = model.selectedSeries[0]
                    .measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index);

                CustomCircleSymbolRenderer.value =
                    value.toString(); // paints the tapped value
              }
            })
          ],
          domainAxis: charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
            tickProviderSpec: const charts.DayTickProviderSpec(
                increments: [15]), // View in increments of 30 days
            viewport: charts.DateTimeExtents(
              start: DateTime(
                  chartData.last.date.year,
                  chartData.last.date.month - 3,
                  chartData.last.date
                      .day), // Start Date 6 months before current date
              end: DateTime(chartData.last.date.year,
                  chartData.last.date.month + 1, chartData.last.date.day),
            ),
          ),
          primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
              viewport: const charts.NumericExtents(-30, 30),
              tickFormatterSpec:
                  charts.BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec.fromNumberFormat(
                      NumberFormat("#.##")),
              tickProviderSpec: const charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(
                  zeroBound: false, dataIsInWholeNumbers: false)),
        ))
      ]),
    ),
  ),
);
```

I pasted the whole part of the chart code. But the one responsible for painting the values are this part of the code

```
symbolRenderer: CustomCircleSymbolRenderer(),
            )
          ],
          selectionModels: [
            charts.SelectionModelConfig(
                changedListener: (charts.SelectionModel model) {
              if (model.hasDatumSelection) {
                final value = model.selectedSeries[0]
                    .measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index);

                CustomCircleSymbolRenderer.value =
                    value.toString(); // paints the tapped value
              }
            })
```

and this part is responsible on painting a rectangle when you click a part of the graph and this is where the value comes from:

```
  void paint(charts.ChartCanvas canvas, Rectangle<num> bounds,
  {List<int>? dashPattern,
  charts.Color? fillColor,
  charts.FillPatternType? fillPattern,
  charts.Color? strokeColor,
  double? strokeWidthPx}) {
super.paint(canvas, bounds,
    dashPattern: dashPattern,
    fillColor: fillColor,
    fillPattern: fillPattern,
    strokeColor: strokeColor,
    strokeWidthPx: strokeWidthPx);
canvas.drawRect(
    Rectangle(bounds.left - 5, bounds.top - 30, bounds.width + 10,
        bounds.height + 10),
    fill: charts.Color.white);
var textStyle = style.TextStyle();
textStyle.color = charts.Color.black;
textStyle.fontSize = 15;
canvas.drawText(charts_text.TextElement("$value", style: textStyle),
    (bounds.left).round(), (bounds.top - 28).round());
```

image:
[here is the sample of the problem. in the chart it paints -7.317 which is the value of the red dot, what I want to achieve is if I tap on the red dot it will show -7.317 and also show the value of the green dot which should be -1.46 and vice versa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Altc.png)

if you are willing to help I can explain it more in depth through meeting. I will also post the deployed version for you to try out the graph. link: https://knndeploy.herokuapp.com/#/

Comment: p.s I am using charts_flutter in here